# how can we prove that $\cup C$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [countably infinite union of countably infinite sets is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55181/countably-infinite-union-of-countably-infinite-sets-is-countable)
>   [proof that union of a sequence of countable sets is countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91366/proof-that-union-of-a-sequence-of-countable-sets-is-countable)

I'm a newbie who try to understand Set Theory. Is there anybody who can explain the solution for the following problem?

Assume that C is a countable set of countable pairwise disjoint sets, how can we prove that $\cup C$ is countable?

Comment: @Asaf karagila Yes, I realized that later, so I deleted my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a bit of the axiom of choice.

Since $C$ is countable we can write its members as $C_i$. For every $i$ fix $f_i\colon C_i\to\mathbb N\times\{i\}$ an injective function.

Now, since these are pairwise disjoint sets the union of he functions is a function, so let $f=\bigcup f_i$ be a function from $\bigcup C$ to $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Prove that this is an injective function, and use Cantor's pairing function to show that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is a countable set.