# Is there a mathematical equivalent to a variadic function?

Tags: functions

I'm looking to express an operation on collections of elements from a set. In programming, this would more or less be a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). Is there an equivalent in mathematics?

Comment: Perhaps a function on the power set of a set?

Comment: That could work, but how would I represent the stop of the collection? So let's just go with a finite version with a maximum of 4 elements in the set. How would I designate a collection of two elements?

Comment: Are repeats allows?  Does order matter?

Comment: Order matters and repeats are allowed.

Comment: There aren't pleasant ways to write this, but the set of interest is $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A^i$ where $A^i$ is the Cartesian product of your set $A$ with itself $i$ times.  See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162443/the-set-of-all-finite-sequences-of-members-of-a-countable-set-is-also-countable).  Each element of this set represents an ordered list of finite length.  You're talking about a function on this set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Continuing from comments)

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then:

- $A^0=\{\emptyset\}$ (this definition is somewhat nonstandard, but helps for your application)
- $A^1=\{1,2,3,4\}$.
- $A^2=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)\}$.

The sets continue, but get larger and I don't want to write them.

Each element of $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A^i$ is an ordered list of elements (throw all the elements of all the different lengths together into a single collection).  You don't need a "stop" because the length is part of the element.

Comment: This should work just fine, and would extend to uncountable indexes in a reasonable way. I'll go with that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still kind of amazed there is no name for this structure.