# Union of two disjoint denumerable sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [countably infinite union of countably infinite sets is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55181/countably-infinite-union-of-countably-infinite-sets-is-countable)

How to prove the union of two disjoint denumerable sets is denumerable?

I want a direct proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hypothesis you have disjoint sets $A=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and $B=\{b_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. You want a bijection $f:\Bbb N\to A\cup B$.

HINT: There is an easy way to define $f$ so that it maps the set of even integers in $\Bbb N$ bijectively to $A$ and the odd ones bijectively to $B$. Where do you think that $f$ should send $2n$? What about $2n+1$?

**Added:** There are at least a couple of ways to write down such a function. You can say:

> For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $f(2n)=\text{thing}_1$ and $f(2n+1)=\text{thing}_2$.

Alternatively, you can give a two-case definition of $f$ like this:

> Let $$f:\Bbb N\to A\cup B:n\mapsto\begin{cases}\text{formula}_1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\text{formula}_2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.\end{cases}$$

The formulas might involve division by $2$, among other things.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that already but i havent learned how to define even&odd numbers..

Comment: @Katlus: I pretty much did it at the end of my answer: the even numbers are the numbers $2n$ such that $n\in\Bbb N$, and the odd numbers are the numbers $2n+1$ such that $n\in\Bbb N$. Or try $$f:\Bbb N\to A\cup B:n\mapsto\begin{cases}\text{something},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\text{something else},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.\end{cases}$$