# First Course in Topology: Countable sets.

Tags: general-topology

Consider nonempty sets $X$ and $Y$, and a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Suppose the inverse image of $Y$ under $f$ is countable for each element of $Y$ and assume $Y$ is countable. Prove that $X$ is countable.

Comment: Did you mean that "the inverse image of each element of $Y$ is countable"? It's unclear as currently written.

Comment: Also, Welcome to MSE! When you post a question, please try to include some context and your attempt at a solution. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

$$X=\bigcup_{y\in Y}f^{-1}\left(\left\{ y\right\} \right)$$
so $X$ is a countable union of countable sets, hence is countable.

Do you understand that? If not then have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55181/75923).